# Not able to pass array data

Tags: php, arrays, json, mysqli

I am trying to create an array in `$data`, but it is not happening. I am using this code to make a day wise sale chart.

```php
$data = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $billdate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("-$i day"));
    $sqlQuery = "select sum(amount),bill_date from msr_bills WHERE bill_date='$billdate' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sqlQuery);

    $fetchamount = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $sum = $fetchamount[0];

    $data = new \stdClass();
    $data->bill_date = $billdate;
    $data->amount = $sum;
    $report_JSON = json_encode($data);

    echo  $report_JSON.",";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge your loop into one query, and then iterate over the results instead:

```
$data = array();
$billdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-10 day'));
$sqlQuery = "SELECT bill_date, SUM(amount) AS amount
             FROM msr_bills
             WHERE bill_date >= '$billdate'
             GROUP BY bill_date";
$result = mysqli_query($sqlQuery);
if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = (object)$row;
    }
    $report_JSON = json_encode($data);
    echo  $report_JSON;
}
```

Note that your date format is not compatible with MySQL dates, which are stored in `Y-m-d` format, and I have changed that in the code. If your `bill_date` column is actually a text field stored in `d-m-Y` format, you will need to convert it in the query like so:

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT bill_date, SUM(amount) AS amount
             FROM msr_bills
             WHERE STR_TO_DATE(bill_date, '%d-%m-%Y') >= '$billdate'
             GROUP BY bill_date";
```

Note also that you can in fact do the computation of `$billdate` internal to your SQL query using date arithmetic:

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT bill_date, SUM(amount) AS amount
             FROM msr_bills
             WHERE STR_TO_DATE(bill_date, '%d-%m-%Y') >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY
             GROUP BY bill_date";
```

And if you are running MySQL 8.0+, you can do the entire operation in MySQL:

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(data) AS data
             FROM (SELECT JSON_OBJECT('bill_date', bill_date, 'amount', SUM(amount)) AS data
                   FROM msr_bills
                   WHERE bill_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY
                   GROUP BY bill_date) d";
$result = mysqli_query($sqlQuery);
if ($result) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $report_JSON = $row['data'];
    echo $report_JSON;
}
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=956ed21bd07c821c88c888164f671f9a)

Comment: If there is no outside input to the SQL then why use PHP at all? All this logic could be moved to SQL.

Comment: @Dharman excellent point. I've made a note about the date computation in the answer. Note that most commonly used versions of MySQL don't support the JSON functions necessary to implement the *entire* code in MySQL.

Comment: @Dharman I've also added code to do all the JSON aggregation in MySQL as well should OP happen to be running MySQL 8+

Comment: Yes... I tried .. and its working fine now... Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Put your echo outside loop. remove code `$report_JSON = json_encode($data);`

```
$respnseArr = array();

{
.
.
.
  $respnseArr[] = $data;
}

echo json_encode($respnseArr);
```